# Detect disconnected socket?

Tags: ios, sockets

I have client iOS app that connects to server.
It uses non blocking socket.

```
int fl;
fl=fcntl(s,F_GETFL,0);
fcntl(s,F_SETFL, fl | O_NONBLOCK);

int set = 1;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, (void *)&set, sizeof(int));
```

- If there is no data then -1 returned by `read`
- If it is disconnected then 0 returned by `read`

But it is not always true. Sometimes connection is lost but -1 is returned.

Is there something like `eof` to detect ?

Answer (score 0):

0 is the EOF. If there is an *error* -1 is returned by read, and you should look at errno to see what it is. The only reliable way to detect a dropped connection in TCP is by writing to it at least twice.

Comment: I have not down voted you. I think it make sense to check `errno != ENODATA` when -1 is returned

Comment: @Max No, it makes sense to check it for `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` if you're in non-blocking mode. `recv()` doesn't set `ENODATA`.